# cannot open include file 'src\gtest-internal-inl.h:' no such file or directory

Tags: googletest

I am trying to compile gmock with Visual Studio 2013.
However, when I compile it, it displsys `cannot open include file 'src\gtest-internal-inl.h:' no such file or directory`.
[image]

But this file does exist and I also already include its path in the project's property.
[image]

When I type its path in this file, it can find it clearly:

[image]

[image]

But VS2013 stills says cannot find it:

[image]

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem today :)
You can copy this header file from googletest/src to googlemock/src directory.
After that, the issue was fixed.

Comment: @firstaccount I tried this but it still gives me the same problem.